# How to remove "number of items" listed at the end of every folder name?

Tags: nautilus, directory

How to get rid of the "number of items" displayed/listed at the end of every folder name?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I am sure someone will help, if you provide more information on this issue.

Comment: Close voters: an answer has been provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-directory-item-counts never` in a terminal, to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

Open up Nautilus (the file manager) and go to **File** → **Preferences**.

[image]

Then go to the **Display** tab, and change the first box to "**None**".

[image]

The first box is what appears under the icons when in normal zoom. When you zoom in, what's in the second box appears, and the same thing for the third box. I remember that, by default, the first box is already set to None. If it's already set to None on your machine, then you're already zoomed in (big icons), so you'll need to change the second box to none.

Once you set it to "None", close and take a look at the file manager. You might need to refresh by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image]